# How to stage selected lines / hunks in diff-mode?

Tags: magit, git, diff-mode

Is it possible to stage changes in diff-mode? Or is this only possible with magit+ediff?

Comment: Please elaborate. Say what you mean by "stage changes". Clarify the reference to magit+ediff.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.  diff-mode is just for showing and editing diffs; [VersionControl](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Version-Control.html#Version-Control) what gets committed, and works only with [files or sets of files](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/VCS-Changesets.html#VCS-Changesets):

> [some] version control systems [...] are **file-based**: each file has its own [...] history [...]. [...] changeset-based [systems' commits] may include changes to **several files**, and the entire set of changes is handled as a unit.